# Checking against the database for a record exist

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

[image]I'm working on another class project and what I want to do is check the database is a row exists.

I've seen several different methods throughout the forum and not one of them seem to work. I've spent roughly 12 hours on this one thing and it's becoming a time sink.

Here is the last iteration of the code I've tried :

```
$ciid = $_POST['categoryid'];

$check = $db->prepare("SELECT categoryid, imgid FROM catType WHERE categoryid = $ciid AND imgid = $imgID ");
    $check->bindParam(categoryid,$ciid);
    $check->bindParam(imgid,$imgID);
    $check->execute();
        if($check->rowCount() > 0 ){
            echo "dqowdhnoqwhd";

            } else {
    /*run working insert */

}

 /* the form that passes the $_POST value */
        echo "<p><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"catname[]\" value=\"".$row['categoryid']."\" />" . $row['cName'] . " </p>";
        echo "<p><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"".$imgID."\" value=\"".$imgID."\"/></p>";
```

As it stands now, I get no errors but it also doesn't tell me that the record is already in the database. When I add a new record , it just duplicates it.

the array :

```
Array
(
    [catname] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )

    [111] => 111
    [icud] => update category
)
```

I ran the query in phpMyAdmin and the formula worked for what I wanted it to do.

Comment: i don't know if it's related. but can you try to remove those `bindParams`? since you already concatinated your values on your prepared statement.`

Comment: Try a simple `$check = $db->prepare("SELECT \`categoryid\`, \`imgid\` FROM \`catType\` WHERE \`categoryid\` = :a AND \`imgid\` = :b"); $check->execute(array(":a"=> $ciid,":b"=>$imgID));`

Comment: Also you note `$ciid` as coming from a post but you don't indicate how `$imgID` is assigned;

Comment: I just tried this and it did the same thing, It throws no error and goes straight to the insert statement .

Comment: Also in your `bindParam()` you are not quoting the `categoryid` or the `imgid`, so presumably those are `constants`?

Comment: Also, `rowCount()` in not reliable in PDO for `SELECT` statements. The manual says to use a `COUNT()` sql statement instead.

Comment: The $imgID I had to stored in a session, so that is a constant on the page. the bindParam was throwing mud at the wall. Like I've stated I've been trying many different iteration of basically the same concept with no luck, I've used this forum along with W3 school and other sites to try and figure this out

Comment: @milken32 is saying the same thing about using `rowCount()` with `SELECT`.

Comment: Spend less time looking at w3schools.com and more time looking at the PHP manual. ;)  PHP has excellent documentation, take advantage of it!

Comment: I've tried to read the manual, but it is written by aliens not of Mars.

Comment: `name=\"".$imgID."\"` how do you propose to retrieve that POST variable by name if its name is always changing?

Comment: $imgID is consistent on that single page. It doe not change. I'm doing some debugging, i'm not getting the categoryid id . object(PDOStatement)#5 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(73) "SELECT imgid , categoryid FROM catType WHERE imgid = 116 AND categoryid= " }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code (e.g. `bind_param()` usage) suggests you want to use a paramaterized query, but you are not leaving any places in the query for the parameters you try to bind. Try this instead:

```
$ciid = $_POST['categoryid'];

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM catType WHERE categoryid = ? AND imgid = ?");
$stmt->execute(array($ciid, $imgID));
$count = $stmt->fetchColumn();
if($count > 0) {
    echo "dqowdhnoqwhd";
} else {
/*run working insert */
}
```

Note from [the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) about `numRows()`:

> If the last SQL statement executed by the associated PDOStatement was a SELECT statement, some databases may return the number of rows returned by that statement. However, this behaviour is not guaranteed for all databases and should not be relied on for portable applications.

Instead, since you're not fetching anything useful from the database you can just do a `COUNT()` of the rows that match. The `fetchColumn()` function will pull the first column of the next row in the result set; handy for pulling a single value out.

Comment: This did not work. It has the same behavior as what I've tried before. I've updated my OP with the array that is being passed.

Comment: Then the data isn't in the database.

Comment: It is in the database. the table is  catTypeid | imgid | categoryid  , it stores the imgid and refrences it with a categorid id in the categories table. so it is a many to many  with catType being auto_incr and a primary key

Comment: I've updated the query, since you don't need any of the returned data. You can give it a try.

Comment: Same behavior, it goes right to the sql insert. I'm following the code though, and understand what you are trying. I'm wondering if the statement is not getting the categoryid from the second array ?

Comment: Then the data isn't in the database. I don't mean the table, I mean that row.

Comment: You don't mention in your question where $imgID comes from. I trust you're setting it, and that you've verified it's accurate with a simple `var_dump()`.

Comment: im starting to think i'm not getting the categoryid correctly updating original post.

Comment: array(3) {
  [116]=>
  string(3) "116"
  ["catname"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
  ["icud"]=>
  string(15) "update category"
}    I don't think i'm catching the categoryid , so im going to work on that  and see if that is the problem.

Comment: you were right, the reason the record didn't exist was because the query failed :)

Answer (score 0):

What I didn't do was run a foreach loop on the array items that was holding the categoryid. So everything that I may have tried for the past , many hours wouldn't have worked. here is my solution, please feel free to suggest improvements

```
n = $_POST['catname'];
    foreach($n as $row => $value){
        $para = $value;
}
$param = $imgID;    
$check = $db->prepare("SELECT imgid , categoryid FROM catType WHERE imgid = $param AND categoryid= $para");
$check->execute();
$count = $check->fetchColumn();             
//echo var_dump($check);
if($count > 0) {
    echo "Category already added";
```